# C# Little-Endian Convert From Java Big-Endian

Tags: java, c#, endianness

This code produces a 32 Length UTF-16 String, i ported it from java. The problem is, the output is different from there to here.

I think the problem lies with the fact Java handles UTF-16 as Big-Endian and C# Little-Endian.

Firstly my string is encrypted using bouncy castle Pkcs5s2, then we go on to put it in a string using the Password_Hash method.

So my question is, how can i make this loop run using Big-Endian, then produce the same string as i would in java.

Answer (score 2):

The only place I see in your code where text encoding even matters is this statement:

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(USER_SALT);
```

And it uses UTF-8, not UTF-16.

You can use Encoding.BigEndianUnicode instead of Encoding.UTF8 if you want a big-endian UTF-16.

Comment: I've also noticed that, but utf-8 is endian agnostic .. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833693/isn-t-on-big-endian-machines-utf-8s-byte-order-different-than-on-little-endian

Comment: Yes, UTF-8 is endian-agnostic. But the OP said he is stuck using UTF-16 because that's what the Java end is using. You can't just decide to use UTF-8 without coordinating with the other end. IMHO, UTF-8 is actually better here, both because endianess becomes irrelevant and because it's usually much more concise than UTF-16. But if you have to use UTF-16, then...well, you have to use UTF-16!

Comment: As you pointed out to use `Encoding.BigEndianUnicode `, the answer may considered helpful.

Comment: I just assumed that it could be something to do with that, seeing as the string would have been UTF-16 to start with. But now i have done more research i understand, with it being UTF-8 i don't have to worry about the endian-ness.

Comment: I do, in fact, still have a major problem though. Can't seem to work out exactly why in c# i am not producing the same has with the same code...

Comment: To start with a given text string and wind up with the same final string representation of the hashed string as in a different implementation, you need to check every detail and make sure you are doing each step exactly the same as in the other implementation: the string must be encoded the same, the same hash algorithm must be executed, and the resulting hashed bytes must be converted back to text the same way. With a concise-but-complete code example demonstrating the issue (including both the Java and C# implementations), a precise answer could be provided. But as it is now, no.