# method String.getBytes() is big endian or litter endian?

Tags: java, jvm, endianness

I need to send String to client socket, for right sequence, the endian is important but I not saw endian information in source code.Does it needn't care about or just I skipped those code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`getBytes()` uses the system's default charset, which means basically all bets are off. It could be big-endian UTF-16, little-endian UTF-16, UTF-8, ISO-8859-1... basically anything.

If you need to specify endianness, or anything about the charset for that matter, you should use [`getBytes(Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-) or [`getBytes(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.lang.String-). There are a [few standard charsets](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html) that all JREs support — including UTF_16BE (big endian) and UTF_16LE (little endian).

Comment: I have some confuse about whether use UTF-8 `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` will decide the endianness way?

Comment: UTF-8 doesn't have endianness. You can read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833693/isn-t-on-big-endian-machines-utf-8s-byte-order-different-than-on-little-endian), but basically, endianness only matters if you read multiple bytes at once, in the same word. UTF-8 is defined as just a byte stream, with no multiple-byte words; even code points that require multiple bytes are defined in terms of multiple 1-byte words. So as a reader/writer, you're just dealing with "next byte, next byte, next byte," in which case endianness isn't a factor.

Comment: @LoranceChen UTF-8 defines the order the bytes should appear for a multi-byte character encoding. It's not really little or big endian as such.

Comment: But why there exist utf-16be and utf-16le. Isn't it does not matter of endinness?

Comment: @LoranceChen UTF-16 is defined not in terms of individual bytes, but in terms of two-byte (=16 bit) words. So, since you have multi-byte words, endianness _does_ matter. Basically, if you're reading UTF-8, you're always asking "give me the next 1-byte word," so the computer doesn't have to negotiate with you over which byte is most significant. But if you're reading UTF-16, you're always asking "give me the next 2-byte word," and for that the computer needs to know which of those two bytes, in the underlying stream is, most significant.