# Why is there no byte-order issue with UTF-8 strings?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, endianness, cpu-word

This question is highly related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833693/isn-t-on-big-endian-machines-utf-8s-byte-order-different-than-on-little-endian), but I'm going to formulate it in a much different way, since I cannot edit the mentioned one.

There is a claim, that the BOM is redundant in UTF-8 encoded strings, since UTF-8 is a "byte-oriented", where the smallest code unit is a byte, and you can always tell from the most significant bits of the byte whether it represents a character by itself or is only a part of a character representation. [The Google JavaScript style guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/javascriptguide.xml) requires to save files in the UTF-8 encoding without BOM, also Jukka Korpela's "Unicode Explained" states that:

> In UTF-8, there is no byte order issue, since the code unit size is one octet. Therefore, using BOM serves no purpose.

Suppose, that there is a UTF-8 string consisting only of ASCII characters, let's say "**abcdefgh**". If I stored it on a machine with another endianness (which uses a 32-bit word), wouldn't it be changed to "**dcbahgfe**", since one character here is one byte, and their order is reversed (stored in the opposite order) on a machine with the opposite endianness?

If this is not the case and the order of bytes is always the same in the memory, and different only in a word (during the processing sort of), then why is the byte order important for the UTF-16 encoding? I.e. if I know, that the encoding is UTF-16 and I address byte 15, I'll know that it is the first byte of the 8th code unit in the string and I need to get the second one in order to find the character or a part of a surrogate pair represented by this code unit.

So could anyone tell me where I'm wrong? I'm pretty sure, I have some misconceptions about the endianness and/or computer hardware, so I would be very grateful if anyone explained this or gave links for further information.

---

*UPDATE*:

So, if there is a UTF-16 string, let's say *abcdefgh* it can be stored somehow in the memory **a0b0c0d0e0f0g0h0** or **0a0b0c0d0e0f0g0h** (with every two bytes swapped, this by the way I do not understand either, why two and not four). And if one is reading this string on a machine with the opposite endian-ness, *even one byte at a time*, he still needs to swap the bytes.

Now, if there is the same UTF-8 string *abcdefgh* it is stored somehow as a sequence of bytes. And the question is **why don't the bytes get swapped in this case**? Or if they do, why doesn't one need to swap them as he reads them? Because, as far as I understand this, to the hardware and software at this level there is no difference between encodings, this is just a sequence of bytes. So **how do the bytes in UTF-16 get swapped and the bytes in UTF-8 don't**?

I'm using *abcdefg* on purpose, to show that there can be (it is not really, I know I'm wrong, but I cannot understand why) an issue even with these simple characters, which take one byte to encode. AFAIK, in UTF-8 one can always tell a, b, c etc. from other characters looking for the most significant bit in the byte. I.e. if he is addressing byte 13 (starting from 1) and it is **01100001** it is definitely the *a* char. It is not known how many there are chars in the string before this one, but the fact that this is the *a* and not a part of some other character's encoding is clear. And now suppose that I read 4 bytes at a time and their values are a, b, c, d. How do I know the intended order?

Comment: Every processor puts the second byte after the first byte.  Endian-ness only affects a memory read that operates on more than a single byte.

Comment: @HansPassant so you mean, that with a UTF-8 string an app is forced to always read one byte at a time. And with, say, UTF-16 the app **can** read two bytes at a time (it might give some performance boost etc.), but also *can* read one byte at a time, and in that case the byte order is irrelevant for UTF-16 either?

Comment: Yes.  You can read utf-16 one byte at a time, but you still have to swap two bytes per coding element if the endian-ness doesn't match.  So that doesn't solve anything, reading two bytes is just more efficient.

Comment: @HansPassant, could you explain then why don't I have to swap bytes of a UTF-8 string if I'm reading one byte at a time? I mean, I have a string **abcd** and I stored it on a big-endian machine. Then on a little-endian one I'm reading 2 bytes from 0 (0 and 1). Wouldn't I get **dc**?

Comment: Utf-8 encodings are variable length, you have to read them one coding element at a time to know the length.  Not otherwise different for utf-16, except that the coding element is 2 bytes instead of 1.  **abcd** just isn't a very good example since that is not how a utf-16 string is encoded.  The little endian version of it would resemble **a0b0c0d0**, the big endian **0a0b0c0d**.  Draw a picture of the actual bytes in memory, usually the easiest way to see it.

Comment: @HansPassant, in the example **abcd** I meant the UTF-8 encoding. You said, that if the encoding is UTF-16, then one needs to swap bytes as he reads them even one at a time. But what I cannot understand, is why isn't this the issue with UTF-8. I mean, to the hardware and software at more lower levels there is no difference between encodings, it is just a sequence of bytes. So why is the string _abcd_ stored on a little endian as **a0b0c0d0** in UTF-16 and isn't stored as **badc** in UTF-8?

Comment: **abcd** is a bad example for utf-8 as well.  Those letters happen to take only one byte per character.  That is not generally true for utf-8, a letter can take up to 4 bytes.  So it could be for example **aabbbcdddd** when a, b and d are not letters in the ASCII character set.  Swapping them two bytes at a time doesn't make sense.  Just keep in mind that endian-ness only matters to the coding element, not the string.

Comment: @HansPassant, I have edited the question, answering your last comment, could you look at it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

32-bit word -> "dcbahgfe": You could view it that way but most processors can access memory in octets (the term is: memory is byte-addressable). So, if you have a packed data structure that is a sequence of bytes, they will have sequential addresses.

If you read and write words and view them as larger integers then you would have to pack bytes in a specific order but that's not an endianness issue, it's an arithmetic one at that level.

---

As far as alignment goes, it is up to compilers and heap libraries. Many will pad between structures so that each begins on an efficient address boundary.

Comment: sorry, I didn't get it. You are saying, that _if you have a packed data structure that is a sequence of bytes, **they will have sequential addresses**_. And _If you read and write words and view them as larger integers then **you would have to pack bytes in a specific order**_. Isn't sequential addresses specific enough?

Comment: Yes, if you have and respect byte-addressability, the address gives the order of your bytes. That's why randomness is not an issue for UTF-8.

Comment: And why then is there the issue with UTF-16? HansPassant said, that even if one is reading bytes one at a time, he still has to swap them respectively. Let's say I have bytes (1-124). I can peek bytes 111 and 112 and find whether it is a character or a surrogate pair. I wouldn't know how many chars are before, what is the index of that char, but I should know the char without swapping the bytes. And still there is the need to swap the bytes (provided I was using the opposite endian-ness machine), as HansPassant said. Don't you know why?

Comment: What order would you read bytes 111 and 112 to form the UTF-16 code unit? You can't tell by their values, you have to use the order specified UTF-16LE or UTF-16BE. But if you can read it as a 16-bit integer then you could plan on someone/something having already ordered them in the same way as the processor.

Comment: I think I'm starting to get it. That is the addresses of bytes are always respected. But the read/write operation can give/store bytes in the opposite orders. And the question about UTF-8 and that it has no byte-order issue is related to the spec of the encoding. That is, if one stores a string *abcd* as UTF-8 this is his responsibility to store these bytes (namely code units, which are one byte here) in the correct order. But if one stores this string in UTF-16 he is only required to store code units (which are two bytes each) in the order and the bytes can get swapped. I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

You have to realize that the endianness of the machine processing UTF-8 or UTF-16 *simply doesn't matter* to answer the question of why there are no byte order issues with UTF-8. All that matters is that UTF-8 and UTF-16 are *byte streams*. UTF-8 is based on 8-bit code units, so there's only a single way to format the byte stream: simply put one byte after the other. UTF-16, on the other hand, is based 16-bit code units. There are two ways to encode a 16-bit value in a byte stream: most significant byte first (big endian) or least significant byte first (little endian). That's why there are two flavors of UTF-16 byte streams, typically called UTF-16-BE and UTF-16-LE.

How an actual computer addresses, reads, and writes memory when processing UTF-8 is a completely unrelated question. A computer might use a weird addressing scheme that complicates UTF-8 processing, requiring byte swaps or whatever. So there might be byte order issues related to a specific architecture, but these aren't byte order issues concerning the specification of UTF-8. An implementation can be sure that there's only one way how a UTF-8 byte stream is formatted.