# Python UTF8 Endianness

Tags: python, endianness

My machine runs on a x86-64 platform, so it should be little-endian, says https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

> The Intel x86 and AMD64 / x86-64 series of processors use the
> little-endian format.

Furthermore, I looked up the character `Ω` (Greek Capital Letter Omega) in here: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/03a9/index.htm

And the corresponding UTF8 encoding of it is: `0xCE 0xA9 (cea9)`

So my conclusion is that the least significant byte (`0xA9`) should come first (lower memory address i.e. lower array index) in a bytearray because of little-endianness of my machine.

But the following code doesn't print the letter Omega:

```
a = bytearray(2)
a[0] = 0xA9
a[1] = 0xCE
st1r = a.decode("utf8")
print(st1r)
```

When i reverse the byte order it does print Omega:

```
a = bytearray(2)
a[1] = 0xA9
a[0] = 0xCE
st1r = a.decode("utf8")
print(st1r)
```

I'm confused!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is fundamentally a question about a technical standard (UTF-8), not a question about programming.

Comment: Where should i ask then?

Comment: The answer is that the concept of endianness is *not relevant* to UTF-8, because UTF-8 is a *variable length* encoding that conceptually consists of *bytes*. When the documentation tells you that the encoding is `0xCE 0xA9`, that means *two bytes*, the byte `0xCE` followed by the byte `0xA9`. These do **not** represent a single 16-bit value.

Comment: Where you should ask is a discussion forum, or [searching the internet](https://duckduckgo.com/?tq=utf-8+endianness). When I do this, I find [an old duplicate of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3833693/isn-t-on-big-endian-machines-utf-8s-byte-order-different-than-on-little-endian) (standards for questions used to be different, and I've found not everyone interprets them the same way I do), as well as [a FAQ from the Unicode consortium](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html).

Comment: `UTF8 encoding` has nothing to do with `CPU` construction. All computers has to create two bytes in order `0xCE 0xA9`.